# scala getting read,write and reject records with simplified regex

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm working on a log file to parse the read/written/rejected records using scala and convert them into a Map. The values are present in different lines - "read" followed by "written" in next line and then "rejected"..

The snippet of the code I'm using is

```
val log_text =
  """
    |server.net|Wed Apr  8 05:44:24 2018|acct_reformat.000||finish|
    |            120 records (              7200 bytes) read
    |            100 records (              6000 bytes) written
    |             20 records (              1200 bytes) rejected|
    |server.net|Wed Apr  8 05:44:24 2018|acct_reformat_rfm_logs
  """.stripMargin

val read_pat = """(\d+) (records) (.*)""".r
val write_pat = """(?s)records .*? (\d+) (records)(.*)""".r
val reject_pat = """(?s).* (\d+) (records)""".r

val read_recs  = read_pat.findAllIn(log_text).matchData.map( m=> m.subgroups(0) ).take(1).mkString
val write_recs = write_pat.findAllIn(log_text).matchData.map( m=> m.subgroups(0) ).take(1).mkString
val reject_recs = reject_pat.findAllIn(log_text).matchData.map( m=> m.subgroups(0) ).take(1).mkString

val log_summ = List("Read",read_recs,"Write",write_recs,"Reject",reject_recs).sliding(2,2).map( p => p match { case List(x,y) => (x,y)}).toMap
```

which results in

```
log_summ: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(Read -> 120, Write -> 100, Reject -> 20)
```

Somehow I feel, I'm doing it in a roundabout/redundant way.. Is there a better way to accomplish this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the similarity of the read/write/reject text, you could simplify the multiple Regex matching patterns into a generic one and use `zip` to generate your `Map`, as shown below:

```
val pattern = """(\d+) records .*""".r

val keys = List("Read", "Write", "Reject")

val values = pattern.findAllIn(log_text).matchData.map(_.subgroups(0)).toList
// values: List[String] = List(120, 100, 20)

val log_summ = (keys zip values).toMap
// log_summ: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] =
//   Map(Read -> 120, Write -> 100, Reject -> 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me. Just three things to improve:

1) `IntelliJ` is your friend. It gives you two intentions immediately:

- `m.subgroups(0)` -> `m.subgroups.head`
- `map(p => p match { case List(x, y) => (x, y) })` -> `map { case List(x, y) => (x, y) }`

2) DRY. Don't repeat read/write/reject related code three times. Just keep it somewhere once. E.g.:

```
case class Processor(name: String, patternString: String) {
  lazy val pattern: Regex = patternString.r
}

val processors = Seq(
  Processor("Read", """(\d+) (records) (.*)"""),
  Processor("Write", """(?s)records .*? (\d+) (records)(.*)"""),
  Processor("Reject", """(?s).* (\d+) (records)"""),
)

def read_recs(processor: Processor) = processor.pattern.findAllIn(log_text).matchData.map(m => m.subgroups.head).take(1).mkString
```

3) `List[Tuple2]` can be converted to a `Map` with a simple `toMap`

```
val log_summ = processors.map(processor => processor.name -> read_recs(processor)).toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in a single pass if you're willing to use the log's wording for the `Map` keys.

```
val Pattern = raw"(\d+) records .*\) ([^|]+)".r.unanchored

log_text.split("\n").flatMap{
  case Pattern(num, typ) => Some(typ -> num)
  case _ => None
}.toMap
//res0: immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(read -> 120, written -> 100, rejected -> 20)
```

Comment: Could you please add explanation on the unanchored?.. right now in travel will check tomorrow.. thanks for the answer..

Comment: **unanchored**: Regex patterns in Scala are, by default, "anchored" to the start/end of the string, meaning, "This pattern describes the entire string from beginning to end." "unanchored", on the other hand, means, "This pattern describes some part of the string, which might, or might not, include the start and/or end."

Comment: **flatMap**: Notice that I'm returning an `Option` (`Some` or `None`) from the map operation. If I had used `map()` the return type would be `Array[Option[(String,String)]]`, which can't be turned into a `Map`. You can use `.flatten` to flatten a collection of `Option[X]` elements into a collection of just `[X]` elements, and all the `None` values will disappear. `flatMap()` is the combination of `map(...).flatten`.